# Aggregate Muliple Post Types in an Array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, syntax

I'm trying to list multiple post types in the same array.

Here's what I'm trying. Unfortunately to no avail:

```
<?php           
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 200, ('post_type' == 'sfwd-topic') || ('post_type' == 'sfwd-lessons'),);
$pages = get_posts($args);
foreach ($pages as $page){ //....
?>
```

How can I get the array to show both post types, sfwd-topic and sfwd-lessons?

The idea is to have a dropdown menu with all posts (up to 200) from both these post types to chose from.

I also tried an in_array version, but I didn't get that to work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to embed an array of all post_type you want to include in the query instead of your conditional way.

```
    <?php
        $args = array (
                  'posts_per_page' => 200, 
                  'post_type' => array( 'sfwd-topic','sfwd-lessons')
        );
        $pages=get_posts($args);
        foreach($pages as $page){
            ?>
```

You maybe need also to add, post_status parameter to include only publish posts.

Reference [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters)

Answer (score 0):

> To get post form different `post_type`, you have to pass an array with multiple `post_type` to `post_type` key.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 200,
    'post_type' => array('sfwd-topic', 'sfwd-lessons')
);
```